# "Open resource" dialog in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am happily using Notepad++ for a long time, but there is one thing that this editor lacks: an "Open resource" dialog, as in Eclipse, that allows opening of files in project folder (and subfolders) by their names. Is there anything like this in N++ world?

Comment: This feature is tied to a project, does Notepad++ support the concept of projects?

Answer (score 4):

After reading more about this [Open Resource](http://greatwebguy.com/programming/eclipse/eclipse-open-resource-shortcut-ctrlshiftr/) dialog, I don't think that Notepad++ has anything that replicates it exactly.

there are two plugins that come pretty close however:

**Explorer** pops up a file explorer sidebar to navigate files

**File Switcher** lets you switch between open files using the keyboard.

You could also use **NPP Exec** to run an external search command like `grep`.

All of those are available at the [N++ plugins](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) page.

Comment: File Switcher is great. Very close to the Eclipse feature (but the file has be open to be found)

Answer (score 0):

This small piece of software could become handy:
http://www.launchy.net/

For more information see:
http://therubyway.wordpress.com/2008/11/23/rails-on-notepad/

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Open Files In Solution](http://www.incrediblejunior.com/npp_plugins) plug-in.

> If you have used Eclipse or Visual Assist(VAX) in Visual Studio you know what this is all about.
>   If not it lets you index specific folders and possible specific types of resources (xml-, cpp, py-files) for a fast indexing of files.